# How to use default database in django testing

Tags: django, testing, django-rest-framework

Now I want to test API using my default database as I need too many data first to mock the request so I don't want to setup test database

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'bills_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '****',
    }
}
```

How can I use it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the same database name for your default and test.

django uses the following pattern to define databases:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'TEST': {
            'NAME': 'mytestdatabase',
        },
    },
}
```

just use `mydatabase` instead of `mytestdatabase`

Comment: `Type 'yes' if you would like to try deleting the test database 'bills_db', or 'no' to cancel: no`
then return `Tests cancelled.`

Comment: try --keepdb to obtain your database

Answer (score 6):

Another option would be to use [Django's database fixtures](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/initial-data/) for the data that is common to all of your environments (test, dev, prod). The added benefit here is that fixtures make it easy to seed a new database with your common data:

```
./manage.py loaddata myfixture1 myfixture2
```

You can create fixures with [`./manage.py dumpdata`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-dumpdata). Here's how to create a JSON fixture from a model called `Author` in the `books` app, for example:

```
mkdir books/fixtures
./manage.py dumpdata --indent=2 --output books/fixtures/author.json books.author
```

Then you can use that fixture in your tests:

```
from django.test import TestCase


class AuthorTestCase(TestCase):
    fixtures = ['author']
    ....
```